# RegExp for Indian Bank Account Number

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression to check for valid bank account number format of major banks in India. Does anyone know what regular expression check should be? Perhaps I just check to make sure all characters are digits?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

RBI dictates certain [rules](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/PublicationReportDetails.aspx?ID=695#UAN) like you've mentioned over Indian Bank Account Number structures (9 - 18).

- Most of the banks have unique account numbers.
- Account number length varies from **9 digits to 18 digits.**
- Most of the banks (67 out of 78) have included branch code as part of the account number structure. Some banks have product code as part of the account number structure.
- 40 out of 78 banks do not have check digit as part of the account number structure.
- All banks have purely **numeric account numbers**, except *one or two foreign banks.*
- Only in the case of 20 banks, account numbers are formed without any pattern with a unique running serial number.

**Indian Bank Account Number Validation Regex:**

```
^\d{9,18}$
```

A better way to validate would be to select the right bank and then have checks in place as per the bank which have been outlined and analyzed by the RBI [here](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/PublicationReportDetails.aspx?ID=695#A3).

Comment: if I could I'd upvote twice, as a a rule, you loosely check such identification numbers (as simple information to help the user out with *probable* typos), but instead you validate the number with the bank or authority.

Comment: @zmo thanks! Yes that's probably the right way. But say you were *to do a client side validation*, would you loosen this to a bigger range of digits as a client side check and then go validate with the authority later?

Comment: well that's why most banks are using a check number at the end, to make it sure the data is unlikely to be gibberish. Otherwise, server-side check is the way to go. Like emails, the bank number has only sense when actually checked against the database for existence. Everything else is just "loose" checking.

Answer (score 4):

According to [RBI](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/PublicationReportDetails.aspx?ID=695#UAN) Reserve Bank of India
-> The bank should have 9-18 digits

```
"[0-9]{9,18}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Name Field Validation**

```
public static boolean nameFieldValidation(String name) {
    System.err.println("Name field input ::::" + name);
    logger.info("nameFieldValidation() :: Start :::");
    try {
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final String NAME_PATTERN = "^(?!\\s|\\.)(?!.*(?:\\s{2}|\\.{2}))[a-zA-Z\\.\\s]+[a-zA-Z]$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(NAME_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
        boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        logger.info(" nameFieldValidation() :: End :::");
        return matches;
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error occurred during name verification: :: Exception ::" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is unclear, please edit and provide more clarity as to why it answers the question.